Stuttering in games: CPU at fault?
5 months ago build a "mid-range" pc:
GPU: Powercolor 6750 XT.
CPU: Ryzen 5 5600.
Motherboard: Gigabyte Aorus Elite B550m.(Bios version is the latest FFc. I believe it's beta because naming ends with lowercase symbol, if it's true then they haven't released stable version for this board since march.)
RAM: Kingston Fury Renegade 32gb XMP #1 - 3600MT/s 16-20-20-20-39-85 1.35V achievable with geardown only. XMP#2 3000MT/s 15-17-17--17-35-65 1.35V(Not on QVL list, though I doubt it's the reason).
SSDs:Samsung 980 Pro Gen 4x4 500gb(100% life), WD SN 550 Gen 3x2 500gb(95% life) and old SATA Kingston SA400(85% life). All updated to latest firmware.
PSU: Thermaltake Toughpower GF3 750W.
Display: LG 75Hz 1080p with Freesync(not premium).
OS: tried only Windows 10 LTSC 2021IoT.
Since the day I build it I experienced stutter problems in almost every game:
Red Dead Redemption 2: tried both DirectX12 and Vulkan(on Vulkan stutters still present, although they're less in ms), on max settings I get 60-85 fps depending on location, but it constantly stutters whenever I travel across the map, when the game loads a lot of assets, even with Vsync on. Also I've noticed it gets completly unplayble when I start chaos on streets of cities, villages, when NPCs around start to take a lot of action. Upon lowering settings seems like it gets better and traversal stutters decrease in quantity, but I can't grasp why on max settings with Vsync On when gpu is maxed at 90-95% usage and cpu at 50-60% there seems to be no apparent bottleneck but still it freezes so bad.
Dead Space Remake: this one absolutely unplayble, though I'm not sure maybe game is unoptimized garbage and there is no fault at my side. I tried max settings ~90-100fps, lowest settings, Vsync on/off, and still stutters are unbearable, aren't related to shader compilation, because they always appear at the same spots whenever I traverse between rooms.
Escape From Tarkov: DX11 game, maybe gpu driver with DXNAVI at fault or game is too cpu heavy, stutters a lot, again, when I traverse a map.
CS2: DX11, first time I tried I was surprised that system couldn't handle this game with smooth framerate on 4:3 1280x1040, 0.1% is horrible though I haven't played it since driver 24.8.1, maybe something changed. To me seemed like stutters were related to shader compilation e.g. when grenade exploded, someone got killed, etc.
Hogwarts Legacy: tried on medium and max settings, stutters when going from different locations.
Valorant: DX11, saw a lot of discussions about how unoptimized this game is on radeon gpus, maybe not my fault.
Kingdom Come Deliverance: DX11, stutters when I load into a save, takes about 10 seconds for them to stop and seems like it gets stable, but then occassionaly stutters when I travel across the map, though Vsync On helps greatly with frametime graph.
Baldur's Gate 3: tried DirectX11 and Vulkan, micro-stutters when I travel across the game world. For some reason turning Vsync On(2 and 3 buffering) increases amount of stutters by great margin.
Star Wars Jedi:Fallen Order: DX11, almost unplayable because of stutters that happen all the time, maybe both compilation and traversal, but it's UE4 title, maybe bad compatibility with radeon gpus.
Cyberpunk 2077: seems like it's very well optimized, tried only with raytracing and FSR, had 1-2 stutters for 5 hours playthrough when entering new areas with huge amount of npcs.
THE FINALS: also seems very well optimized, have few stutters(1-2) each 1-2 games, sometimes I don't have them for 3-4 games in a row.
Watch Dogs 2: DX11, unplayable, constant traversal stutters.
The Witcher 3 Wild Hunt remastered: tried only DirectX12 with raytracing, stuttered once every 10-15 minutes, couldn't understand if it's traversal or shader problem.
Satisfactory: DX12, UE4, stutters a lot during movement through the map.
Ready or Not: stutters a lot and probably due to shader compilation when someone joins the server, kills npc, grenade explodes, etc. Tried highest and lowest settings, no difference.
Detroit Become Human: a lot of stuttering when traversing the world, sometimes just when moving player camera.
Control: DX12 with ray-tracing, stuttering when moving through locations, also sometimes during action scenes, when shooting, throwing objects, etc.
I think I tried almost every thing except changing CPU,GPU, motherboard:
-Tried different display, tried Freesync on/off.
-Tried different PSU and RAM sticks(Not QVL also).
-Tried removing SATA SSD.
-Removed USB 2.0 and 3.0 header, basically no front panel.
-Re-fitted CPU, GPU, RAM sticks, SSDs.
-Powered GPU with 2nd separate PCIe cable.
-Once I took whole motherboard out of the case, checked everything was properly fitted and powered and tried testing system like that.
-Tried enabling/disabling TPM, SMT, ReBAR, PBO in BIOS, MPO, set shader cache to "On" in Windows.
-Tried overclocking CPU, GPU, RAM.(Set it to 3800MT/s 16-19-19-19-36-55, Infinity Fabric to 1900, also tightened up secondary timings, boosted voltage to 1.5).
-Tried underclocking GPU and also setting min core clock to max-100Mhz.
-Tried different GPU drivers, even from 2023.
-Monitored thermals, cpu max is ~60°C, while GPU ~65-66°C for core/edge( I don't know where sensor is) and 95-96°C for hotspot. Yeah, delta is abnormally high, but I figured it's ok for amd gpus and still within normal thermal range. Other sensors from motherboard don't exceed 50-55°C.
-Re-installed Windows ~10 times, once tried with disabling different background services, with no Windows Defender, disabling cpu mitigations for games, setting battery power plan to "Ultra performance, high performance", all to no visible performance gain/difference.
I did some testing with HWInfo( polling rate at 100ms)




Upd: tried disabling C-States in BIOS, same stuttering. Seems like CPU is really the bottleneck, but then why so many games, even old ones, exhibit same behavior where stutters occur when CPU busy/C0 state residency spikes?

"Star Wars Jedi:Fallen Order: DX11, almost unplayable because of stutters that happen all the time," - I had to disable my security software (Acronis)  when I had this problem with SWJFO. Windows Defender isn't the cause of your issues.

This sounds a lot like I/O blocking IMO. I think your images are only showing the CPU usage for the game, so might not include CPU usage from other sources which might briefly cap out if you have an intermittent process kicking off. Also I think I recall reading some Samsung nVme drivers causing issues (resolved by using Microsoft ones), which might implicate any of the SSD drivers (if applicable). If you have any "storage driver cruft-style" software, research it to see if it is actually useful or required

@Yorik, do you know of any software that could display overlay of cpu busy/wait time for other processes other then active game?

@Yorik, I never installed any drivers for my SSDs, the only software present on my current Windows is Steelseries GG which controls my headset, mouse, keyboard. But I don't think it installs its own drivers.

I would actually remove steelseries to eliminate it as a problem. These types of software, especially RGB lighting control drivers are actually notorious for causing issues.

@Yorik, I just tried deleting the software, then I disabled some leftover stuff in Device Manager, but stuttering still persists. I'm gonna try re-install Windows 10, but install only chipset and GPU drivers without any Windows' updates just to test if anything changes.

Have you looked in the event viewer for Timeout Detection and Recovery (TDR) errors (soft gpu reset), oh and maybe look into "latencymon" software

latencymon is mostly used for diagnosing real-tme audio processing problems but it is a handy tool for looking at possible culprits

I looked into TDR on this site https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000156216/troubleshooting-the-timeout-detection-and-recovery-feature-within-windows. But it seems like it happens only when timeout is greater than 2 seconds, which is a lot of time in gpu compute sense, I've never seen such big stutters, doubt that I encountered that particular problem, but I'll still monitor it. I've tried latencymon before, it displayed some unknown drivers as being biggest in latency, but maybe it's normal during heavy gaming, need to research it further.

GIGABYTE software is known to have conflicts.

@Ramhound, I never installed it
